# Inconsistency while inserting documents in MongoDB, with MongoJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongojs

I am building a site with ExpressJS and MongoDB. I am using MongoJS for establishing the connection with the DB.

Problem:
Inconsistencies while try to insert documents in to the MongoDB. Roughly 1/3rd of insert requests fail.

Code:

```
function insertWorkouts(callback,new_workout){
  var workout_date = new_workout['date'];
  db.latest_workout.insert(new_workout,{continueOnError: true, safe: true}, function(err, result) {
   console.log("DBconn insert!!");
   if(err) { console.log(err);
     throw(err);
   }
   else {
     console.log(" DBConn Inserted workout");
     // function invocation to insert workout dates
   }
  });
}
```

Please suggest how I can ensure that all my inserts go through succesfully.

Edit:
MongoDb Connection:

```
var db = mongojs('mongodb://{username}:{password}@ds025xxx.mlab.com:25973/{DB name}', ['users','trainer','client','athlete','workout','client_feedback','IntermediateWorkout_Template','latest_workout','workout_dates','response_dates','sent_dates','diet','payment']);
```

PS: This is my first question here. Please ignore my mistake(s).

Comment: You never call `callback()` when you're done, I notice.

Comment: Good catch, I will update it. Do you think it would resolve my issue ?

Comment: Please add how you connect the mongodb client and also model of latest_workout if any , for better understanding .

Comment: @Himanshusharma, updated the question. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was able to figure out the problem, largely thanks to the comment by Patrick Roberts. 
I had missed out crucial callback().

If anyone ever encounters something similar, check your callbacks().

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/), it's a great ODM(Object Document Mapping), it means Mongoose translate data in the database to JavaScript objects for use in your application.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
// create connection.
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
```

Declare its Schema :

```
var testSchema = mongoose.Schema({
 name: String
});
```

We've got a schema with one property, name, which will be a String. The next step is compiling our schema into a **Model**.

```
var Test = mongoose.model('Test', testSchema);
```

Each document can be saved to the database by calling its save method. The first argument to the callback will be an error if any occured.

```
var test = new Test({name:"Thor"});
test.save(function (err, doc) {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    console.log(doc);
    // Doc will contain record saved in db.
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Will try it.